# Am I over-using Nullable types?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I'm setting all fields to nullable types where the back-end database fields they correspond to allow nulls.  Good?  Bad?

---

The long version:

It works just fine, I just feel like I might be abusing the fact that I can make stuff nullable.

Basically it's an internal application for employee management that ties into our SQL database.  I'm using a three layer structure, from presentation to back-end: Business Objects --> Business Logic --> Data Access.

For my Employee object, I have the following fields:

```
    public class Employee : Person
    {
       private EmployeeTitle? _employeeTitle = null;  //enum
       private EmployeeType _employeeType;  //enum
       private DateTime _startDate;
       private DateTime? _endDate = null;
       private EmployeeInsuranceRecord _employeeInsuranceRecord = new EmployeeInsuranceRecord();

       //...
    }

    public class EmployeeInsuranceRecord
    {
       private int? _employeeInsuranceRecordID = null;
       private string _alienRegistrationNumber = null;
       private string _healthInsuranceNumber = null;
       private string _unemploymentInsuranceNumber = null;
       private string _welfarePensionNumber = null;
       private DateTime? _insuranceAcquiredDate = null;

       //...
    }
```

And in my database:

- EmployeeTitleID allows nulls.  An employee may start in a trial period for example, without a set job title.
- EmployeeTypeID does NOT allow nulls.  Even if an employee is a guest or on a trial period, this must be explicitly selected for record purposes.
- StartDate does NOT allow nulls.  If someone is going into the database, we need to know when they started.
- EndDate however, does allow nulls.  Anyone currently employed doesn't have an EndDate yet.
- I instantiate an EmployeeInsuranceRecord object on Employee instantiation, but each field within EmployeeInsuranceRecord is nullable because the EmployeeInsuranceRecords go into a separate table linked via an ID, therefore an Employee can exist without an EmployeeInsuranceRecord (common for people just starting, still in the initial paperwork process).  By instantiating the EmployeeInsuranceRecord from the get-go, I can keep my presentation layer cleaner by not having the instantiate any classes there.  This has no impact on performance, given the small scale we're working with.

Comment: Simply put, if you need 'em, you need 'em.

Comment: This is exactly how I would prefer to do my column type mappings.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  This was a huge help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One annoyance of nulls is the coding overhead to keep checking for null before dereferencing / consumption of the value - you will probably need to use a bunch of static extension methods to make your life easier.

But much better to use null than to kluge a 'magic value' like DateTime.MinValue etc - this not only corrupts data but may pose problems when persisting to the database if you forget to map it back to null.

As you describe, some of the values become mandatory as they are 'state' dependent (e.g. EndDate is required when the employee resigns / retires / is fired). You need to split out your validation strategy based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Making the fields nullable is necessary for representing your business data. What you are doing looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're modeling the database correctly. I would even say that if you were **not** using nullable types here, you would be introducing bugs into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use nullable types when your database table columns are defined as nullable ones. Otherwise you won't be able to match your model properties with the DB columns.

Besides on the performance aspect there is no difference and you don't need to worry about using nullable or non-nullable types

Answer (score 0):

You should only allow nulls if the property or field is not mandatory. Otherwise you should just come up with a way to either let the user specify the value or set a default value (which you can also do for field that are not mandatory btw). If the code you specified reflects the situation where a lot of fields are optional, than it's just fine. Although I was a bit wondered why you have nullable enums....